# Probability theory without non-measurable sets - what would it be like?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, soft-question, axiom-of-choice

It is known that the axiom of choice is required in order to construct a non-measurable set. I believe (though I'm very far from understanding the details) that the existence of [Solovay's model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model) shows that there are alternative set theories (of the form ZF + other stuff) in which "every set is measurable" is a theorem; and moreover that you can have this as a theorem while still keeping at least some of the more useful parts of real analysis.

So, assuming I'm correct about the above: suppose things had developed differently, and we had developed probability theory in a set theory where we can still do calculus, but there are no non-measurable sets. My question is, what practical differences would this make for applied probability theory and related fields such as statistics and information theory?

Presumably you wouldn't need to specify a sigma algebra when defining a measure, and in my naïve imagination this would make it generally simpler to reason about probability distributions over infinite sets. But would there be any major consequences beyond that? Would any important probability-related theorems become false, or conversely, would there be new theorems that are false in ZFC but could be useful in applied probability theory? Or would the differences necessarily be only minor?

(Note that for the purposes of this question I'm only interested in the impacts on probability theory and related topics. For example, I don't care whether every vector space has a basis or not, unless it can be shown that this would have an impact on a result in information theory or statistics, etc.)

Comment: There would be no [atomless] finitely additive probability measure on the natural numbers.

Comment: I don't know much about the Solovay result, but I guess that it only shows that (in a suitable universe) *every subset of the reals is Lebesgue measurable*. I would be very surprised if it rules out the existence of non measurable sets in general, which you seem to be thinking.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Solovay's result indeed shows that it is *consistent* that every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable. In this case, if you understand that a universe of set theory *can be* "the universe of mathematics", why not accept *this* set theory? Yes, you'd need to reject the axiom of choice, but you'd still have Dependent Choice, which is enough to have a lot of analysis, and all sets of reals will be Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: @PhoemueX: If you'll open Garnir's paper from 1974 titled *"Solovay's axiom and functional analysis"* you will see him excitingly suggest that functional analysis (and indeed, the functional analysts) will be split into "Zornian" (assuming AC), "Solovayan" (assuming all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable), and "constructive" (not relying on either option). Perhaps to his dismay, this never really happened, although quite a few interesting things can happen to analysis in Solovay's model. (See http://karagila.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/axiom-of-choice-in-analysis.pdf for a quick survey.)

Comment: @Asaf: Thanks. I will look at your link in more detail. However, my main point was that the question by the OP implicitly suggests that essentially for every measure space, you will (be able to) use the full power set as the sigma algebra, even though (as far as I know) Solovay is mainly talking about the Lebesgue measure on the real line.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Yes, but in *most* cases one works with some standard Borel space, one way or another, and with some Borel measure. Which in Solovay's model can be completed to be total.

Comment: @AsafKaragila you might be talking at cross purposes - I think PhoemueX is just pointing out a basic error in my question. I had assumed that in the Solovay model there are no unmeasurable sets of any kind (not just no Lebesgue-unmeasurable subsets of the reals), hence you can always just use the full power set as the sigma algebra. If this is correct it's interesting, but I am guessing PhoemueX is correct in pointing out that it's an error.

Comment: (I'm sorry for asking such a naïve question. I really don't know much about measure theory and was just trying to work out whether it "has to be that way", even if you don't fully accept the axiom of choice. If @PhoemueX's comments are correct then it really does have to be that way, even in the Solovay model.)

Comment: Nathaniel, I don't really know a lot about probability. But if you consider probability as the study of a standard Borel space with some associated probability measure which is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure, then the situation is that you're always dealing with Lebesgue measurable sets, which in Solovay's model always include *all* the subsets of your space. Sure, you can define a $\sigma$-algebra which is not everything (e.g. Borel sets) and then there are sets which are non-measurable, since they are not Borel. But the completion is still everything.